# In SQL Server, why is 12538335.3 not decimal(10, 4)?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, why is 12538335.3 not decimal(10, 4)? Nor is it `decimal(11, 4)` but it is `decimal(12, 4)`.

```
CREATE TABLE T (d decimal(10, 4) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO T (d) 
VALUES (12538335.3)
-- Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

ALTER TABLE T ALTER COLUMN d decimal(11, 4)

INSERT INTO T (d) 
VALUES (12538335.3)
-- Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

ALTER TABLE T ALTER COLUMN d decimal(12, 4)

INSERT INTO T (d) 
VALUES (12538335.3)
-- OK
```

Comment: Because you aren't counting the 3 zeroes to the right of the `.3`. `Decimal(10,4)`  means **always** a maximum of (10-4) digits for the int part and 4 digits for the decimal part. In this case, `12538335` has 8 digits, not 6

Comment: If you'd **consult the documentation** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql), you'd see that the two numbers means the **total** number of digits (10), and the number of digits after the comma (4). So `decimal(10,4)` means: 10 digits **total**, of which 4 after the decimal point (so therefore: 6 **before** the decimal point). Your numbers are just **too big** to fit your datatype!

Comment: 12,538,335.3  there are 9 significant digits in this number; 1 of which is a decimal.  So 9,1 would work.  The reason your's don't is 4 digits to the right of the decimal only leaves 6 to the left of it.  meaning the 8 numbers left of the decimal wouldn't' fit thus overflow.  but if you needed to store 99,999,999.9999 then you'd have to have (12,4)  8 digits to the left, 4 to right total 12.

Comment: So silly me for thinking that the _total number of digits_  in `12538335.3` is 9?

Comment: That's not silly, but the docs are clear, `(10,4)` means 4 decimal digits and (10-4) digits for the int part

Comment: Yes, total number of digits used in this particular number is *9* - but that's not relevant. You've defined it as `dec(11,4)` --> means **7** digits (11 -  4) before the decimal point, and 4 (or fewer) after. But your number is **8** digits before the decimal point --> it just doesn't fit (even if you're not using all of the "after-the-decimal-point" digits)

Answer (score 3):

Precision and Scale...

12,4 is 12 total digits with 4 to the right of the decimal. 12538335.3 is 9 digits... but when you account for the extra 0's for the scale defined in `decimal(12,4)` you get `12538335.3000` which is 12 total digits. Thus, this scenario works.

11.4 doesn't work, because 11 (precision) digit's isn't enough to account for the extra 0's on the end for the scale you have declared (4).

This is the same for 10,4

```
declare @var decimal (12,4)
set @var = 12538335.3
select @var 
--returns
12538335.3000
```

Answer (score 1):

The misunderstanding arises from the phrase *total number of digits*.

It means the total number of digits after the number is padded with zeros on the right to fill the scale.

Answer (score 0):

[ 1 ]

> [...]why is 12538335.3 not decimal(10, 4)? Nor is it decimal(11, 4)
>   but it is decimal(12, 4).

Well, according to [SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sql-variant-property-transact-sql) it's NUMERIC(9, 1):

```
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(12538335.3, 'BaseType') AS DataType,
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(12538335.3, 'Precision') AS [Precision],
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(12538335.3, 'Scale') AS [Scale]
/*
DataType Precision Scale
-------- --------- -----
numeric  9         1    
*/
```

where

- 9 = total number of digits (left side of decimal separator + right
  side)
- 1 = number of digits after separator.

For this data type, maximum value is 999,999,999.9

[ 2 ] Following piece of code

```
CREATE TABLE T (d decimal(10, 4) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO T (d) 
VALUES (12538335.3)
```

is trying to insert 12538335.3 / `NUMERIC(9,1)` (`8digits . 1digit`) into a `NUMERIC(10,4)` (`6digits . 4digits`). Because target data type / NUMERIC(10,4) has only 6digits for the left side of decimal separator (compared with 8 digits required for 12538335.3) above INSERT statement generates an exception:

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
```

that basically means

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric(9,1) to data type numeric(10,4).
```